# Hot to get client context from external site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint site (e.g. https://site1.sharepoint.com/). The Visual Studio generates code to get client context for current site. I need to get the client context from external site (e.g. https://site2.sharepoint.com/) by URL. I need to open login page for second site (probably using OAuth protocol), then create client context and use it with the first client context (to copy the data between them). How I can do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you're able to authenticate to the site, it is doable.

Here's an example of obtaining the client context.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yoursite");
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
context.Load(list);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Read more here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399156/SharePoint-Client-Object-Model-Introduction

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But your code works only for current site. I can not find information about getting context from another site, that's why I asked the question here.

Comment: What errors are you getting?